# How to Scrape a Dynamically Loaded Form

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I need some help. I need to download financial statements that are located in PDF files to my MAC using Python. I've tried this using Selenium but unfortunately haven't been able to make progress.

Following is the URL: [psx](https://financials.psx.com.pk)

When I load this URL, the page looks like so: [image]

you see the dropdown on the left "Company Name...", I need to select a company name there. Which, I can select using following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="driver-path")
driver.get("https://financials.psx.com.pk/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("country")
drp = Select(elem)
drp.select_by_value("SHEL")
```

Once I do that, then I see a window like this: [image]

Every link under reports, when clicked downloads a PDF. I require those PDFs. The problem is that the URL doesn't change after `Selection` but the form is updated with the new page. How can I access this updated area using Selenium? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to do this way

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://financials.psx.com.pk/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("country")
drp = Select(elem)
drp.select_by_value("SHEL")

time.sleep(10)

for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@target="_blank"]'):
    element.click()
    time.sleep(1)

driver.close()
```